# Regex - Capture every line based on condition

Tags: c#, regex

To revisit a solution I had here over a year ago:

```
/* ----------------- jobnameA ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameA   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 1


/* ----------------- jobnameB ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameB   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: tu,we,th,fr,sa
condition: s(job1) & s(job2) & (v(variable1) = "Y" | s(job1)) & (v(variable2) = "Y" 
alarm_if_fail: 1
job_load: 1
priority: 10


/* ----------------- jobnameC ----------------- */ 
...
```

I use the following regex to capture each job that has uses a variable *v(x)* in its condition parameter (only jobnameB here matches):

```
(?ms)(^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*([\w-]*)[\s-]*\*/)((?:(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*?condition\: ([^\n\r]*v\([^\n\r]*)[ \t]*\))+(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*)
```

I now need each line caught as parameter and value groups while satisfying the same conditions.

This regex will get each line with parameter and value as separate capture groups, but this wont take into account the presence of variables *v(x)*, so it grabs all jobs:

```
(?:^([\w_]*\:) ([^\n]+))
```

And, the following expression will get me as far as the first line (insert_job) of the satisfying jobs, but it ends there instead of grabbing all parameters.

```
(?:^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/)(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*?(?:^([\w_]*\:) ([^\n]+))
```

Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider parsing this input reading in the file line by line and filling out entries once you see `/* ---` at the start of the line?

Comment: A single regular expression to parse out these seems inefficient. Consider multiple expressions?

Comment: I did try doing it step by step, capturing each job individually and then passing the set of parameters to another function as a string where I ran the second regex match....something was happening where it was no longer matching the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be much easier if you broke it up into steps. I am using LINQ for this:

```
var jobsWithVx = Regex.Matches(src, @"(?ms)(^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*([\w-]*)[\s-]*\*/)((?:(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*?condition\: ([^\n\r]*v\([^\n\r]*)[ \t]*\))+(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);

var jobParameters = jobsWithVx.Select(j => Regex.Matches(j, @"(?ms)^([\w_]+\:) (.+?)$")).Select(m => m.Cast<Match>().Select(am => am.Groups));
```

Then you can work with the job parameters:

```
foreach (var aJobsParms in jobParameters) {
    foreach (var jobParm in aJobsParms) {
        // work with job and parm
    }
    // alternatively, convert to a Dictionary
    var jobDict = aJobsParms.ToDictionary(jpgc => jpgc[1].Value, jpgc => jpgc[2].Value));
    // then work with the dictionary
}
```

Sample that runs in LINQPad:

```
var src = @"/* ----------------- jobnameA ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameA   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 1


/* ----------------- jobnameB ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameB   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: tu,we,th,fr,sa
condition: s(job1) & s(job2) & (v(variable1) = ""Y"" | s(job1)) & (v(variable2) = ""Y"" 
alarm_if_fail: 1
job_load: 1
priority: 10


/* ----------------- jobnameC ----------------- */
";

var jobsWithVx = Regex.Matches(src, @"(?ms)(^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*([\w-]*)[\s-]*\*/)((?:(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*?condition\: ([^\n\r]*v\([^\n\r]*)[ \t]*\))+(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*[\w-]*[\s-]*\*/).)*)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);

var jobParameters = jobsWithVx.Select(j => Regex.Matches(j, @"(?ms)^([\w_]+\:) (.+?)$")).Select(m => m.Cast<Match>().Select(am => am.Groups));
jobParameters.Dump();
```

Comment: on jobsWithVx.Select: 'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you sure you copied it all? I tested in LINQPad and it runs fine using your sample input as a `string`.

Comment: Absolutely, typed it twice, copy-pasted, and typed again.  Input is a text file, but jobsWithVx is correctly collecting the 73 jobs that satisfy the regex.  Not sure why the Select() isnt working on jobsWithVx in the next step.

Comment: I d/led LINQPad 4 and 5 to try this and I received the same error in both.

Comment: I added an exact copy of my LINQPad.

Answer (score 1):

I've been parsing text files for over 40 years.  If I can't do it nobody can.  I tried for awhile to use Regex to split your 'name: value' inputs but was unsuccessful.  So I finally wrote my own method.  Take a look what I did with the days of the week

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Job.Load(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Job
    {
        public static List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();

        public string name { get;set;}
        public string job_type { get;set;}
        public int date_conditions { get; set;}

        public DayOfWeek[] days_of_week { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }

        public int alarm_if_fail { get; set; }
        public int job_load { get; set; }
        public int priority { get; set;}


        public static void Load(string filename)
        {
            Job newJob = null;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if ((inputLine.Length > 0) && (!inputLine.StartsWith("/*")))
                {
                    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> groups = GetGroups(inputLine);

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> group in groups)
                    {
                        switch (group.Key)
                        {
                            case "insert_job" :
                                newJob = new Job();
                                Job.jobs.Add(newJob);
                                newJob.name = group.Value;
                                break;

                            case "job_type":
                                newJob.job_type = group.Value;
                                break;

                            case "date_conditions":
                                newJob.date_conditions = int.Parse(group.Value);
                                break;

                            case "days_of_week":
                                List<string> d_of_w = new List<string>() { "su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa" };
                                newJob.days_of_week = group.Value.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => (DayOfWeek)d_of_w.IndexOf(x)).ToArray();
                                break;

                            case "condition":
                                newJob.condition = group.Value;
                                break;

                            case "alarm_if_fail":
                                newJob.alarm_if_fail = int.Parse(group.Value);
                                break;

                            case "job_load":
                                newJob.job_load = int.Parse(group.Value);
                                break;

                            case "priority":
                                newJob.priority = int.Parse(group.Value);
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetGroups(string input)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> groups = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            string inputLine = input;
            while(inputLine.Length > 0)
            {
                int lastColon = inputLine.LastIndexOf(":");
                string value = inputLine.Substring(lastColon + 1).Trim();
                int lastWordStart = inputLine.Substring(0, lastColon - 1).LastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
                string name = inputLine.Substring(lastWordStart, lastColon - lastWordStart);

                groups.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string,string>(name,value));
                inputLine = inputLine.Substring(0, lastWordStart).Trim();
            }
            return groups;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it works as well, I just went with the other one for simplicity.  Thanks.

Comment: Great if you understand regex,  Still with the regex you still have to parse the regex results.  My code does everything in one method.

Comment: Your code doesn't take into account the requirement of v() in the condition parameter, so it processes all jobs in the file.  And the way it's parsing sequentially, it would already create a job object and populate parameters before we find that it's actually not valid, which is why I wanted to try the regex route.

Comment: It wasn't clear in the posted data what is v().  I assumed that you could filter results after all the data was parsed.